# How can I get hidden_states from BertForSequenceClassification?

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model

I read the official tutorial(https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html) and tried to set config, but it doesn't work.

```
from transformers import PretrainedConfig
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased", num_labels=2)
model.config.output_hidden_states = True
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('../parameter.pkl'))
model.cuda()
output = model(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

Output should be a list that holds the hidden states. I expect that because you are loading the `parameter.pkl` which may not have output hidden states by default, it is overwriting your `config.output_hidden_states` to False? See what happens if you set it to True after loading the state_dict?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I changed the order as you suggested, howeve r output receives only clasification tensor.
```array([[ 5.155039 , -5.1482654],
       [-1.7462035,  3.0982263],
       [ 5.295436 , -5.6735516]], dtype=float32)```

Comment: What happens if you just comment out the `model.load_state_dict` ? If it works after commenting out, then you know the error lies with loading the state dict.